# JSTL 2d Array Iteration

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a 2d array stored in a java bean and I'm trying to iterate through its contents to print a corresponding table on a JSP page. The array is a bean data member which I'm accessing through the EL code ${board.cells}. I tried to do this with a c:forEach tag, but it's only printing a single cell. I know the array contents are valid, as I can see them when I index them directly by ${board.cells[0][0]}

Here's my loop code, embedded in the JSP.

```
<c:forEach items="${board.cells}" var="row">
    <tr>
        <c:forEach items="${row}" var="cell">
            <td><img src=${cell} align="" alt="cell"></td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you seeing that single cell in browser UI or also in generated HTML source?

Comment: i'm seeing it in the browser ui

Comment: The JSTL looks fine to me, you've double checked that the array is more than 1x1 and it returns a path for each image? Generated source is the actual HTML, Ctrl + U is the shortcut to see the source on most browsers

Comment: My generated source looks like this:                                                       <c:forEach items="[[Ljava.lang.String;@3ca52888" var="row">
                    <tr>
                        <c:forEach items="" var="cell">
          <td><img src="" align="" alt="cell"></td>
                  </c:forEach>
  </tr>
      </c:forEach>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, JSTL core tags are simply not been interpreted/parsed. They are been sent plain to the HTML response. You need to declare the JSTL core taglib in top of your JSP to get them to run.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: Ahh thank you. That fixed my problem. I was using the JSTL library in my IDE... kinda confused why it didn't work. I'll try to add that one to my library.

Comment: You're welcome. I however don't get your comment about the IDE. If you're confused as to how JSTL is supposed to be installed/configured, please visit the linked wiki page.